# Pattern Matching in logstash cofiguration using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

**msg filed data:**

```
Starting RentalTransaction <invoice iid="80000000-41fb-1638-07a3-ffff08d24473"
```

**grok pattern is:**

```
[<]*[iI]nvoice[_,\" \"][iI][iI][dD]= %{UUID:InvoiceIID}
```

I am unable to parse this data using this pattern.Can anybody provide the correct pattern for this.

I am testing with this using  link

http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Common regular expression for grok matching pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447198/common-regular-expression-for-grok-matching-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following grok pattern works:

```
[<]*[iI]nvoice[_,\" \"][iI][iI][dD]=\"%{UUID:InvoiceIID}\"
```

Basically, you had an unnecessary space, and the double quotes around the UUID were not present.

Comment: Wow, that sounds and looks familiar.

Comment: @AlainCollins, I posted my answer only couple of seconds after yours, and noticed yours only after. I would've deleted my answer if it were same but yours had a mistake in forgetting to escape the double quotes.

Comment: You don't have to escape double quotes in the debugger, or if you're building a patterns file.  I was mostly complaining that the OP liked your answer and didn't like mine, considering they were identical in explanation and content.  C'est la vie!

Answer (score 1):

The input has no space after the "=" but your pattern does.

The input has quotes around the UUID, but your pattern doesn't.

Grok is a game of precision.

```
[<]*[iI]nvoice[_,\" \"][iI][iI][dD]="%{UUID:InvoiceIID}"
```

Comment: It works in the Heroku debugger, where I tested it for you.