# Common regular expression for grok matching pattern

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I need the common **RE** for representing the below values

```
Invoice_IID: 00000000-4164-1638-e168-ffff08d24460
Invoice_IID 00000000-4164-1638-e168-ffff08d24460
invoice iid 00000000-4164-1638-074f-ffff08d24461
<invoice iid="00000000-4164-1638-074f-ffff08d24461"
<invoice iid=\"00000000-4164-1638-074f-ffff08d24461\"
<parent_invoice iid="00000000-4164-1638-074f-ffff08d24461"
```

I am trying with the below configuration with my grok debugger like

http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result

```
grok { 
  match => { "msg" => "[iI]no*voice[_,\" \"][iI][iI][dD]:? %{UUID:InvoiceIID}" } 
}
```

I need the common support for all types of content in one **Regular Expression**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I **got the solution** for all above types of data.

**matching pattern is:**

```
grok { 
  match => { "msg" => "[<]*[parent_]*[<]*[iI]no*voice[_,\" \"][iI][iI][dD][" "]*:?[" "]*=?[\\,\"]*%{UUID:InvoiceIID}[\",\\]*" } 
}
```